# Remove string in list that is substring of another string if both are in the list

Tags: python, string, list

Imagine you have a list of lists as follows:

```
list = [['Hello','Hello World','something else'],
 ['Hello','something'],
 ['somethings']
 ['Hello World','something else'],
 ['Hello','blabla','Hello World']]
```

I would like to remove the 'Hello' in the list if and only if 'Hello World' is in it.

What I have tried:

```
new_list = [elem.remove('Hello') for elem in lista if 'Hello' and 'Hello World' in elem]
```

However, I get the following error:

```
list.remove(x): x not in list
```

And my list becomes this:

```
[['Hello World', 'something else'],
 ['Hello', 'something'],
 ['somethings'],
 ['Hello World', 'something else'],
 ['Hello', 'blabla', 'Hello World']]
```

So it worked for the first row, but then it broke.

Extra points for computational efficiency!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a an inner list comprehension to filter `"hello"` values:

```
l = [['Hello','Hello World','something else'], ['Hello','something'], ['somethings'], ['Hello World','something else'],['Hello','blabla','Hello World']]
new_l = [[c for c in i if c != 'Hello'] if 'Hello World' in i else i for i in l]
```

Output:

```
[['Hello World', 'something else'], ['Hello', 'something'], ['somethings'], ['Hello World', 'something else'], ['blabla', 'Hello World']]
```

Comment: Wouldn't this make it O(nm^2) instead of O(nm)? Being m the inner size of the array and n the size of the array (we got O(m) for the in and O(n) for the loop and we would be doing a second O(m) loop)

Comment: @AntonioLópezRuiz I believe it is just `O(mn)` as `str in i` is `O(m)`, but `[c for c in i if c != 'Hello']` is not being run for every pass over `i` being made by the internal looping of `str.__contains__`. It would simply be `O(n)*(O(m)+O(m)) => O(mn)`.

Comment: You are right, it doesn't pass every time, would be like an additional #of times it passes, which honestly is small. Would only be O(nm2) if it goes into that if every time.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies here:

```
if 'Hello' and 'Hello World' in elem
```

This does not work how you think it does. `if 'Hello'` is a separate clause, which always evaluates to `True` since `'Hello'` is not an empty string. You need to write out the full test both times:

```
if 'Hello' in elem and 'Hello World' in elem
```

Separately, writing this as a list comprehension doesn't quite make sense since `list.remove` modifies the original list, and doesn't return anything. Your `new_list` will just be full of `None`. Just use a `for` loop:

```
for sub_list in my_list:  # also note, you should not use `list` as a variable name. 
    if 'Hello' in sub_list and 'Hello World' in sub_list:
        sub_list.remove('Hello')
```

If you actually don't want to modify the original list / sub-lists, you'll need to create new lists explicitly instead of using `remove`:

```
new_list = []
for sub_list in my_list:
    if 'Hello World' in sub_list:
        new_sub_list = [elem for elem in sub_list if elem != 'Hello']
    else:
        new_sub_list = sub_list[:] # make a copy to avoid referencing the original
    new_list.append(new_sub_list)
```

This whole thing *can* also be written as a nested list-comprehension if you want:

```
new_list = [sub_list[:] if 'Hello World' not in sub_list else 
            [elem for elem in sub_list if elem != 'Hello']
            for sub_list in my_list]
```

But in either case, I'd probably prefer the explicit for loop construction just for clarity.